# See this beautifull scraper

Tags: support, scraping, phishing

I was wondering if some tag excerpt was plagiarised, so I entered it into Google's search engine. It turned out there was no result for the copied excerpt besides on two SO pages, and one hit on a scraper/phishing duplicate. Hence link in the spoiler.

> http://www.yeyajichangjia.DONOTCLICKxyz/?/?questions/tagged/qualcomm (remove the DONOTCLICK if you really want to go there)